# Use Cell Reference and Date as File name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a VBA to save excel sheet as a PDF and i'm trying to save the file name based on a number of variables, im having a little trouble with the function though please could someone point me where im going wring please:

```
 pdfName = ActiveSheet.Name
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
fileSaveName = ActiveSheet.Name & Range("A3:Q3").Text & Range("Q3").Text & Date("ddmmyyyy").Text .PDF

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    fileSaveName _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & fileSaveName
```

Comment: what is not working as it should with your code? i.e. what is happening?

Comment: Note by putting Range("A3:Q3") etc you are implicitly referencing the activesheet. You might want to be explicit with sheet names. And you might want to use Format with Now if you are trying to put today's date on the end of the filename string.

Comment: We can't tell you "what's going wrong" if we don't know the definition of "right"...  Could you [edit] your post to share some more information about *what you have, what's doing wrong, and what you're trying to do?*  Also, see "[mcve]" as well as great tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in same sheet try

```
With ActiveSheet

    fileSaveName = .Name & .Range("A3:Q3").Text & .Range("Q3").Text & Format$(Now,"ddmmyyyy")

End With
```